# How does Spring Cloud Config understand the external properties?

Tags: java, spring, git

My question is how will a spring boot application which is pushed on cloud understand that it has to use so-and-so properties file that is stored in Git and referred in Spring Cloud config server?

I understand a cloud config server will have the Git repository url, etc. 
and
a binding of spring-boot application with the spring cloud config service should happen, 
but still I don't understand how an application understands that it has to use a properties file stored externally?

Answer (score 0):

Name the properties file in the Git repo that is used by the Config server like:

```
/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
```

Meaning if your client app is name `mysoapapp`, create a file: `mysoapapp-dev.properties`. Now run `mysoapapp` passing the active `Spring` profile: dev, using argument: `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

You should also confirm that the Config server is able to serve the files by sending a request like:

```
curl -v http://<the config server>/mysoapapp-dev.properties
```

and it should retrieve the properties.

I published a couple of blog posts about this topic that might help you:

- [Centralized and versioned configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/09/Centralized-and-Versioned-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-and-Git.html)
- [Refreshable Configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server, Spring Cloud Bus, RabbitMQ and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html)

Comment: If I am not using spring profiles then ? I should name my properties file as mysoapapp.properties?

Comment: I don't remember, I can try once I get to my laptop, in the mean time, could you also try it?